# Get PyTorch tensor values into python set

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, pytorch, tensor

I've a set of pytorch tensors of integers representing image masks (shape is `(1, x, x)`), I don't have the labels and I need to grab them manually from this pytorch tensor.

Is there an effective way to get these values into a set without having to iterate over every cell.

Comment: are you looking to torch.unique?

Comment: more elaboration needed!

Answer (score 0):

Had to work out something similar, for a 1D tensor:

```py
set(torch.unique(all_labels).tolist())
```

Where `all_labels` is the 1D tensor with duplicated elements. In my case this is to get the set of labels for a confusion matrix for a sample of data where all labels are not always present.